# Is there anyway to use path along with placeholder in Ramda?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm trying a few things in Ramda and I stuck on trying to get a property value deeply inside a object using purely Ramda.

I only was able to do it wrapping a function to receive that missing part of a path:

```
const fn = property => path(['a', 'b', property, 'd', 'e']);
fn('c')({ a: { b: { c: { d: { e: 1 } } } } });
```

I also tried to use `R.__` but it simply doesn't work:

```
path(['a', 'b', __, 'd', 'e'])
```

How can I get `1` inside that object using purely Ramda, provided that missing prop thru the result function?

Comment: `flip` will not work in that case, because you are using it inside an array and an array is just 1 parameter. It looks like using a wrapper function for the missing part of the path is the cleanest way - sometimes Ramda is not more concise than plain ol' JavaScript.

Comment: A comment about "pure Ramda":  I'm one of the founders of Ramda, and I find that notion frightening.  Ramda is simply a library that you can use to make it easier to perform a certain style of coding.   It is not a framework dictating how you write your code.  Unless this is simply an exercise to learn Ramda better, I would suggest that you use Ramda where it helps, and skip it where it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer to the "Call of the Question" (instructive):**

```
const fn = R.pipe(
  R.insert(2, R.__, ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']),
  R.path(R.__, { a: { b: { c: { d: { e: 1 } } } } })
)

fn('c') //=> 1
```

**Answer to the "Actual Question" (assumes irrational data flow):**

```
const fn = R.compose(
  R.path,    // see NOTE
  R.insert(2, R.__, ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'])
)

fn ('c') ({ a: { b: { c: { d: { e: 1 } } } } }) //=> 1
```

Your question *implies* that you will know the object that will be queried before you will know the missing path key ("Call of the Question"). If you will know the path key before you will know the data, then just use the below method to solve for the data instead of the path. If you will know the missing key and the data at the same time, then you can just call the function or depending on the situation may want to use a combinator which is beyond the scope of the question.

NOTE: In Ramda, `pipe` will work the same as `compose` reversed, so you can use `pipe` instead and switch the arguments; however, other libraries have stricter definitions of `compose` and `pipe` which will limit `pipe`'s arguments to unary functions, so `compose` is preferred despite, in this instance, being equivalent.

**Explanation:**

You are on the right path, you just need a slight realignment with a couple concepts.

First, `R.__` is meant to take the place of an unknown argument (the entire argument). Here, you are incorrectly attempting to use `R.__` within an argument. Consider the following:

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y
const curriedAdd = R.curry(add)

// the following are equivalent
const add2 = placeholder => add(placeholder, 2)
const add2 = curriedAdd(R.__, 2)
```

Hopefully, it is clear from the above that `R.__` is simply a way of saying: "Hey Javascript, I don't know the value of this argument yet, please save the arguments that I do know and wait to run this function until I know the rest of the arguments." It is syntactic sugar around the solution you presented in the question (which, by the way, is a perfectly acceptable way to approach the problem).

Second, you just need to break down your problem a little more. Start with the information you know and work toward what you do not know. Your question presumes that you know all of the elements of your path except for one; however, you also know the index of the missing property, i.e., `2`:

```
// from question
['a', 'b', property, 'd', 'e']
```

It is strange that you would know all of the other elements of the path and the index of the unknown key, but hey, this is hypothetical, I assume. In such a case, `R.insert` and `R.__` can be used to represent the known and unknown information:

```
R.insert(2, R.__, ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'])
```

Your question *implies* that you will know the object that will be queried before you will know the missing path key ("Call of the Question").

```
// from question
{ a: { b: { c: { d: { e: 1 } } } } }
```

If you don't know all of the elements of your path, then you will not know the complete path until `R.insert` is called. Conversely, once `R.insert` is called you will know the full path. First, consider what `R.path` will look like where you do not yet know the path:

```
R.path(R.__, { a: { b: { c: { d: { e: 1 } } } } })
```

So, putting it all together:

1. We will not know the full path until we call the `fn` with the missing key.
2. Once we know the path, we can call `R.path` to retrieve the value.

This sort of step by step flow of data is basic function composition and can be expressed succinctly with `R.pipe`.

Again, it is strange that you would know the data and all of the path keys except for one. However, the above method and thought process can be transferred to your real-world situation which will likely *not* rely upon `R.insert` but *will* require you to build your path step by step and then pass said path to `R.path`.

Comment: I really loved this answer - you really get involved to the situation even when it looks like strange. Also thanks for explaining why a placeholder doesn't work here - now I got it.

Comment: I also prefer using `pipe` because it facilitates when you read your code - it follows the" top to bottom" natural way to read things.

Comment: I choose `compose` for single-line invocations and `pipe` for multi-line ones.  I really like how `compose(f, g)(x)` visually maps to `f(g(x))`, but that is lost over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping with a function is a good solution in this case, and this what I would use.

For the sake experimenting, you can use a lens to set the the 2nd index. Wrap `R.path` with `R.useWith`, and create the path array using `R.set` with `R.lensIndex`:

```js
const { useWith, path, lensIndex, set, __, identity } = R;

const fn = useWith(path, [
  set(lensIndex(2), __, ['a', 'b', undefined, 'd', 'e']),
  identity
]);

console.log(fn('c', { a: { b: { c: { d: { e: 1 } } } } }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting use of the placeholder.  It certainly isn't directly supported, but it's reasonably straightforward how to write a function that uses it in this way.  While Ramda's [`_isPlaceholder`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/internal/_isPlaceholder.js) is a strictly internal function, we can use the same mechanism in our own code to build a function such as you're suggesting:

```js
const countBlanks = compose (length, filter (prop ('@@functional/placeholder')))

const fillArgs = ([p = undefined, ...ps], [a, ...as], res = []) =>
  p == undefined
    ? res
    : p ['@@functional/placeholder']
      ? fillArgs (ps, as, [...res, a])
      : fillArgs (ps, [a, ...as], [...res, p])

const partialPath = (ps) => 
  curryN(countBlanks (ps) + 1, (...args) => path (fillArgs (ps, args), last (args)))  


const obj = {a: {b: {c: {d: {e: 42}}}}}

console .log (
  partialPath (['a', 'b', __, 'd', 'e']) ('c') (obj),
  partialPath (['a', __, 'c', __, 'e']) ('b', 'd') (obj),
  partialPath ([__, 'b', __, __, 'e']) ('a') ('c', 'd', obj)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script>
<script> const {__, compose, length, filter, prop, curryN, path, last} = ramda </script>
```

Obviously you can inline `countBlanks` and `fillArgs` if you don't want them exposed.  There are obviously plenty of different ways to write `fillArgs`.  I simply find this sort of recursion more pleasant than looping.

Comment: @RichardForrester: Thanks... I guess.  I'm curious as to your reaction.  Why do you see this as impractical?  Do you mean the API is odd or that something about the implementation is impractical?

Comment: I just mean that, `partialPath` - it's such a quirky thing to do, i.e., hard to imagine actually using it in real practice; but still, really cool how you made it. IDK, maybe it is practical - maybe I'll be working on something later today and think, I know exactly what this needs... `partialPath`!

Comment: @RichardForrester: I imagine it might be more useful if the api was `partialPath (nodes) (obj) (...missingNodes)`, but that's a minor change.  Imagine `const statePopulation = partialPath (['countries', 'usa', 'provinces', __, 'population']) (data) ; /* ... */  statePopulation('NY') //=> 19542209`.  And clearly we could picture others with several holes.  So it does seem to have some reasonable uses.